# String replacement in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

How to replace a character is a string in Objective-C?

Answer (score 806, accepted):

You could use the method

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

...to get a new string with a substring replaced (See [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW25) documentation for others)

Example use

```
NSString *str = @"This is a string";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"string"
                                     withString:@"duck"];
```

Comment: I thought the point of having NSString and an NSMutableString subclass was because an instance of NSString is *unchangeable*. While--like any sane person, I'd rather have ducks than strings any day--the fact that you just overwrote the contents of `str` just blew my mind.

Comment: But I guess the adress of `str` changed in the process

Comment: it doesn't change. str now contains a whole new string. stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString does NOT mutate the string. It simply return a new string.

Answer (score 22):

`NSString` objects are immutable (they can't be changed), but there is a mutable subclass, [`NSMutableString`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableString), that gives you several methods for replacing characters within a string. It's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 10):

If you want multiple string replacement:

```
NSString *s = @"foo/bar:baz.foo";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/:."];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s); // => foobarbazfoo
```

Answer (score 8):

It also posible string replacement with stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:

```
for (int i = 0; i < card.length - 4; i++) {

    if (![[card substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] isEqual:@" "]) {

        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
        card = [card stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"*"];

    }

} //out: **** **** **** 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in old versions on the iOS. in the latest, the right-to-left works well.
What I did, is as follows:

first I check the iOS version:

```
if (![self compareCurVersionTo:4 minor:3 point:0])
```

Than:

```
// set RTL on the start on each line (except the first)  
myUITextView.text = [myUITextView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                                           withString:@"\u202B\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *stringreplace=[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"search" withString:@"new_string"];
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)