# Some maths questions on Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I just have two questions on Obj-C.
I have a string value: "234.67". How can i change the dot to comma? Resulting 234,67?

Another questions is, how work the split/division on Obj-C? I have a value, 255.45 and i want to divide it twelve times.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c

Comment: Can't understand this: "Another questions is, how work the split/division on Obj-C? I have a value, 255.45 and i want to divide it twelve times." ... what do you mean by divide twelve times and what would this have to do with splitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace the period with a comma, you should replace it in the string when you want to display it.

```
NSString *str = @"234.67";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"."
                                     withString:@","];
```

To divide you just use the operator

```
float j;

j = 234.67 / 12;
```

Good Luck.