# Replace all characters in a string

Tags: objective-c

Hi I've searched but can't find the answer I'm looking for or I'm not reading it right.

I have a NSString  I use

```
NSString *string1 = [infolist objectAtIndex:0];
NSUInteger len = [string1 length];
```

Is it possible to replace all characters not white spaces with say a * or some other unreadable character.

Example:   `this is a string`  to   `**** ** * ******`

Comment: probable [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/668228/1367611)

Comment: @ВидулПетров this isn't a duplicate. The link that you gave is quite far different from what mrgonuts is trying to do. He wants the whole string to be replaced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of regular expressions if you target OS X 10.7 and later:

```
NSString *originalString = @"This is a string";
NSString *nonspaceRegexp = @"\\S"; // = /\S/
NSStringCompareOptions options = NSRegularExpressionSearch;
NSRange replaceRange = NSMakeRange(0, originalString.length);
NSString *replacedString = [originalString
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:nonspaceRegexp
                                                      withString:@"*"
                                                         options:options
                                                           range:replaceRange];
NSLog(@"%@", replacedString); // **** ** * ******
```