# How to ignore whitespaces in regular expression

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iPhone.I have a small doubt in regular expressions that at present i am using regular expression below one in my project that is

```
NSRegularExpression *regularExpression = 
   [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"href=\"(.*).zip\"" 
                                             options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                               error:&error];
```

it searches the website viewsource and gives results which are in below pattern

```
href="kjv/36_Zep.zip"
href="kjv/37_Hag.zip"
```

but one of the link in view source is like below

```
href="kjv/38_Zec.zip        "
```

i want to ignore the white spaces after the .zip 
how it is possible if any body know this please help me

Comment: [Parsing HTML/XML with a Regex will never end well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Consider using an HTML or XML parser instead and extract that attribute.

Comment: one thing to note. If the web page has a url with spaces on the end. the browser will include %20 or + for each space in the url. for example kjv/38_Zec.zip++++++++ would be the url for the last one in your example which is a UTF8 Encoded version of the URL

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do a string replace of all whites spaces with the empty string or use a strip function on that string to remove all trailing spaces. Refer [String replacement in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c)

If you don't want to do that, use the pattern for empty space in your regular expression to match one or more white spaces.

`\s` includes `\n(ewline) \r(eturn) \t(tab) \v(ertical tab) \f(orm feed) and space`. If you want only space use `""` which is actually a blank space.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the examples you provided with the following regex...

```
@"href=\"(.+)\.zip\s*\""
```

I modified your regex by adding

1) + (matches 1 or more of the preceding character) to capture the entire name before the .zip, 
2) \ to the . to prevent it from matching all characters,
3) \s* to match (skip in your case) zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose its given a NSString *test = @"...href="/functions?q=KEYWORD\x26amp...  " and you want to perform actions on this string with NSRegularExpression, you could also do easy method call like this

```
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [testRegex firstMatchInString:[test stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];
```

And dont change anything in your NSRegularExpression.

Answer (score 0):

I commonly use groups to gather the item I want. However you need to know how groups work.

Unfortunately You cannot name them. but think of it this way.

groups are indexed with numbers for the () encountered.

0 is the entire match.

1 is the first set of ()

2 is the second set of () and so on.

if you have a group set like this.

```
NSString *matchString = @"(href)=\"((.*)[.]zip)\"";
```

you would have 4 groups.

Group 0 is the entire string, Group 1 is the "href", Group 2 is the entire filename and group 3 would be the filename without the extension.

Hope that helps.

```
NSRegularExpression *regularExpression = 
   [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"href=\"(.*[.]zip)[^\"]*\"" 
                                             options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                               error:&error];

NSMutableArray *foundMatches = [NSMutableArray array];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:originalString 
                        options:0 
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalString length]) 
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         if (result.numberOfRanges == 2){
                             [foundMatches addObject:[originalString substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]];
                         }
                     }];
```

the match I used here would mess up in the event there is a .zip in the filename that does not include the extension.

e.g. href="my.zip.file.zip" would put match group 2 would be "my.zip" as opposed to "my.zip.file.zip"