# Replace special character or whitespace with -

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, character

I want to make every string look like this:

```
"this-is-string-one"
```

So main string could contain:

```
"This! is string, one"
```

So basicaly replace !?., whitespace and characters like that with "-".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this is best handled by a regular expression:

```
NSString *someString = @"This! is string, one";
NSString *newString = [someString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[!?., ]+" withString:@"-" options: NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, someString.length)];
NSLog(@"\"%@\" was converted to \"%@\"", someString, newString);
```

The output will be:

> "This! is string, one" was converted to "This-is-string-one"

The regular expression `[!?., ]+` means any sequence of one or more of the characters listed between the square brackets.

Update:

If you want to truncate any trailing hyphen then you can do this:

```
if ([newString hasSuffix:@"-"]) {
    newString = [newString substringToIndex:newString.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: can i cut off somehow if - is last: "sting-strong-" need "sting-stong"