# how to replace space with dash in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Hey folkks I'm working with an api that search about movies now the problem is when i type single word in UISearchBar it works but when I type space for another word it dose'nt work.Near query=%@ when i type single word it works but when I type another word with space it won't

```
NSString *movieName=searchBar.text;
NSString *movieString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd81709e87b1209433c49",movieName];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:movieString];
```

Comment: I think you should replace space with %20 or +

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String replacement in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace Space with Dash you new to URL Encode your string

Below is an example of encoding your string to URL Encode

```
NSString *movieName=searchBar.text;
movieName = [movieName stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLUserAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSString *movieString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd81709e87b1209433c49",movieName];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:movieString];
```

Comment: @Jageen Yes Previous code will also encode https://, updated my answer, now it will encode only Movie Name

Comment: Important: You should do that for *any* parameters you add to your URL. Even if they can't contain spaces, there are other characters that may not occur in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
formattedString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code.

```
NSString *movieName=searchBar.text;
NSString* replacedMovieName = [movieName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No need replace space with dash, need to add **Percent Escapes** in string before creating `NSURL`.

Use `NSString` class method:

```
-(NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Like,

```
NSString *movieName=searchBar.text;

//This is what you need
movieName=[movieName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *movieString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd81709e87b1209433c49",movieName];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:movieString];
```

***OR***

Alternately you can do following(Not best approach):

```
NSString *movieName=searchBar.text;

//This is what you need
movieName = [movieName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *movieString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd81709e87b1209433c49",movieName];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:movieString];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *movieName=searchBar.text;
movieName = [movieName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];//use vice-versa
NSString *movieString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd81709e87b1209433c49",movieName];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:movieString];
```