# Remove \\U00a0 from string - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've a following string received from server.

```
body = "Subject: This is from webportal \nTo: My Account \n...\n\n\nLTD Emojis:100k:ltd:eyes:trophy    \nDefault Emoji \\ud83d\\ude1b\\ud83d\\ude31\\ud83d\\ude0d \\ud83d\\ude3b\U00a0\\ud83d\\ude48     \n-- \nStephen acc";
```

I want to remove "\U00a0"from string. Here is code to remove that but its not working.

```
testString=[testString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U00a0" withString:@""];
```

is there any other way to get this thing done.

Comment: You should refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c) question.

Comment: which one.... ?

Comment: click on the link, the "this"

Comment: Thats fine. I'm using same method. For any other character it will work fine.

Comment: May be you have added \\U00a0 occurrence  instead \U00a0. just a guess :)

Comment: \U00a0 doesn't work.

Comment: It seems like its not a compatible string, so string operations won't work on it. \U00a0\\.... is having error while as string.

Comment: why its not compatible?

Comment: Try to collect your response in NSString or assign this to new NSString * obj, error will be shown to you. May be ask the server(or where ever you get this response) why is it formatted so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135386/discussion-between-sagar-in-and-aqsa-arshad).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who got this issue. This was a simple change in this line. It solved my problem.

```
testString=[testString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@""];
```

Comment: `u00a0` is a non-breaking space, so it's probably more desirable to replace it with " " instead of eliminate (replace with "") it.